# Антиспам на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота, python, библиотека aiogram, функционал состоит в том , что бы пользователь отправляя определенную фразу , получал рандомный анекдот , но мог написать эту фразу не чаще чем раз в минуту , а если уж и продолжал спамить то получал в ответ что то типо "Новый анекдот будет доступен через {n} секунд" , и по окончанию "таймера" смог бы снова получить анекдот написав эту фразу. Может кто то знает как реализовать такой антиспам?